# Указатели после delete

Tags: c++

Какое будет значение указателя после вызова операции `delete` для объекта, на который он указывал? `0`, `NULL`, `nullptr` или левый адрес?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Такое же как и до `delete`. Оно не меняет значение указателя.

Comment: Разве не зависит от того, был ли переопределен `delete` ?

Comment: А можно тогда как-то проверить, свободна ли память по этому указателю?

Comment: У меня есть список указателей на объекты пользовательского класса. Я прохожусь по списку вызывая спец. методы, которые внутри могут сделать delete this, а могут и не сделать. Мне надо знать удалился ли объект и убрать указатель на него из списка.

Answer (score 1):

Будьте осторожней с конструкциями типа `delete this`. Лучше подумайте, как можно изменить архитектуру проекта.

Например, при таком раскладе число 3 в консоли вы уже не увидите:

```
class DangerClass
{
  public:
    bool dangerMethod(bool condition = true)
    {
      if (condition)
      {
        delete this;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
};

bool func1(DangerClass* ptr)
{
  return ptr->dangerMethod();
}

void func2()
{
  std::cout << "1";
  DangerClass dc;
  func1(&dc);
  std::cout << "2";
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::cout << "0";
  func2();
  std::cout << "3";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Я также воспользовался советом @Abyx, и просто сделал методу возвращаемое значение и по нему уже смотрю удалять элемент из списка или нет. Так как у меня список хранит unique_ptr, то и объект соответственно удаляется.